# Using a variable name as a function in LESS

Tags: less

Using LESS, is it possible to have a 'variable' function name? Say, for example, I have many elements that use the darken function, but I want (in another use instance of the same stylesheet) to use the lighten function. Is it possible to have the functions themselves defined as a single variable? Like one can in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)?

For example

```
.element1 {color: darken(@color1, @percent);}
.element2 {color: darken(@color2, @percent);}
.element3 {color: darken(@color3, @percent);}
```

to become

```
.element1 {color: lighten(@color1, @percent);}
.element2 {color: lighten(@color2, @percent);}
.element3 {color: lighten(@color3, @percent);}
```

with the change of a single line of code?

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help), it will be help you to arise your content quality

Comment: In this particular case you also may just invert `@percent` value, since `darken(@color, 50%)` is equal to `lighten(@color, -50%)` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use mix-ins as functions if you declare you're mix-in as follows...

```
.adjustLight(@c, @p){
    color: darken(@c, @p);
}
```

and that mixing can be used as you'd expect...

```
.element1 {.adjustLight(@color1, @percent);}
.element2 {.adjustLight(@color2, @percent);}
.element3 {.adjustLight(@color3, @percent);}
```

This will allow you to change the `adjustLight` mixin without affecting the rest of your css declarations. There are good examples in the online documentation about [Parametric Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) and [Mixins as functions](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature)

Comment: Thanks @Leo, for what it's worth, I tried it out here http://jsfiddle.net/Keef_X/114xp5xp/